# Setting the global Data type and rounding mode with Python

Tags: python, ieee-754

I am trying to do some computation with different data types. I want to try floating and fixed-point arithmetic.

For fixed-point arithmetic, I want to set the format globally e.g. integral part equal 3 digits and fractional part equal 4 digits (123.5848).

For floating-point, I'd like to to globally set the data types to either decimal32, decimal64 or decimal128 of the ieee754 - 2008 standard.

Can you advise how to do it?

Comment: These are two separate questions, one for fixed-point which I'm sure is already answered somewhere (tl;dr use the `decimal` module), and one for floating-point.

Comment: For floating-point you may need to recompile your Python interpreter, see https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#the-standard-type-hierarchy, section `numbers.Real`.

Comment: Pretty sure decimal ieee-754 usage is infeasible with Python unless you go to extreme measures or pick specialized libraries. Are you sure you don't want binary32 or 64, which are readily available?